# How to test browser functionality of popups using Chromedriver (such as for Payment Request API)

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, stripe-payments, laravel-dusk, payment-method

How can I write browser tests for modals like this?

[image]

In case it matters, I'm using [Laravel 5.6 Dusk](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/dusk) for browser testing, and my payment request modal is generated via a [Stripe Payment Request Button](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/payment-request-button).

Stripe's Payment Request Button uses the cross-browser [Payment Request API](https://www.w3.org/TR/payment-request/) from W3C.

Chrome doesn't let me "inspect" the HTML of the elements of the modal, so I'm not sure how to write compatible commands in the form of `$browser->click('.selector');`.

Comment: That isn't actually a modal; it's built into the browser. I'm not sure if testing that is even going to be possible, to be honest, so I'm not sure what to recommend here.